# Panda > Statsmodel: syntax errors implementing variance_inflation_factor

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I am "using" `Statsmodel`for less than 2 days and am not at all familiar with the import commands etc. I want to run a simple `variance_inflation_factor` from [here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence.variance_inflation_factor.html) but am having some issues. My code follows:

```
from numpy import *
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import scipy, scipy.stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
from statsmodels.api import add_constant
from numpy import linalg as LA
import statsmodels as sm

## I have been adding libraries and modules/packages with the intention of erring on the side of caution 

a = df1.years_exp
b = df1.leg_totalbills
c = df1.log_diff_rgdp
d = df1.unemployment
e = df1.expendituresfor
f = df1.direct_expenditures
g = df1.indirect_expenditures

sm.variance_inflation_factor((['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']), g)

then I get the following error:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-bb126535eadd> in <module>()
----> 1 sm.variance_inflation_factor((['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']), g)

AttributeError: module 'statsmodels' has no attribute 'variance_inflation_factor'
```

Can someone direct me to the proper syntax for loading and executing this module? If it is more convenient that I post a link to some source code please ask. However, I have a feeling that this is just a simple syntax issue.

Answer (score 2):

The function `variance_inflation_factor` is found in `statsmodels.stats.outlier_influence` as seen [in the docs](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/_modules/statsmodels/stats/outliers_influence.html), so to use it you must import correctly, an option would be

```
from statsmodels.stats import outliers_influence
# code here 
outliers_influence.variance_inflation_factor((['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']), g)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I applied your import code but there is some sort of problem implementing `outliers_influence.variance_inflation_factor((['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']), g)`. I am getting a `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'`. I am going to update the question and see if I can play around with the code to get it to work.

Comment: Please don't update the question - it is a separate issue. If you have another question, do everything within your power to try and solve it, and then if you still can't figure it out you can return to ask Stack Overflow and ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for asking this question!  I had the same question today, except I wanted to calculate the variance inflation factor for each of the features.  Here is a programmatic way to do this:

```
from patsy import dmatrices
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor

# 'feature_1 + feature_2 ... feature_p'
features_formula = "+".join(df1.columns - ["indirect_expenditures"])

# get y and X dataframes based on this formula:
# indirect_expenditures ~ feature_1 + feature_2 ... feature_p
y, X = dmatrices('indirect_expenditures ~' + features_formula, df1, return_type='dataframe')

# For each Xi, calculate VIF and save in dataframe
vif = pd.DataFrame() 
vif["vif"] = [variance_inflation_factor(X.values, i) for i in range(X.shape[1])]
vif["features"] = X.columns
vif
```

Please note the above code works only if you have imported `pandas` and df1 is a `pandas DataFrame`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = df1.years_exp
b = df1.leg_totalbills
c = df1.log_diff_rgdp
d = df1.unemployment
e = df1.expendituresfor
f = df1.direct_expenditures
g = df1.indirect_expenditures

ck=np.array([a,b,c,d,e,f,g])
outliers_influence.variance_inflation_factor(ck, 6)
```